# Blank page issue for OpenCart site

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I'm getting blank page when I go to URL http://www.example.in/

But when I  open link http://www.example.in/index.php?route=common/home I can see my website with assigned theme.

I checked error logs from admin panel. But didn't found any error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death

Comment: Can you provide us with the files you have in your sites root directory? I have feeling it has to do with either your `.htaccess` or a stray `index.html` that is being favored over `index.php`